# Solving cos(x)-sqrt(x) using Newton Raphson method for x ∈ [0,4]

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, newton-raphson

I am trying to solve to the equation

```
f(x) = cos(x) - sqrt(x)
```

using Newton-Raphson Method in python

```
f'(x) = -sin(x) - (1/2*sqrt(x))
```

For my starting guess, I'm trying values form 0 to 4. It works fine from the range 0.00001 to 2.45

The graph looks like this
[image]

> But my code fails (gives nan) when I enter values beyond 2.45. It also
>   fails at 0. I'm not able to understand the mathematical logic behind
>   this. Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: I got this here $$.6417143709$$

Comment: The reason why it fails at $0$ is because you will have $0$ in the denominator somewhere in your expression.